# a checker of links in python

Tags: python, http, url, syntax-error

I have to create a function in python which searches links in an HTML page and then for every link, check if the link is broken or not.

Firstly I've created a function which searches every link (broken or not), no problem and stores them in a array called "g".

Secondly, I thought to create an array "a" which contains only the broken links by checking every item/element in array "g".

I don't know why, the check link by link doesn't work in the function. But if I copy a link and paste it like a parameter in function on the shell, it works.

```
import urllib.request
import re
import urllib.error

def check(url):
    try:
        f= urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError :
            return False
    return True
def trouveurdurls(url):
    f= urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    b=(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
    d=re.findall('<a href=".*</a>',b)
    liste=[]
    f.close()
    for el in d:
        g=re.findall('"https?://.*\.*"',el)
        liste.append(g)
    a=[]
    for el in liste:
        chaine= ''.join(map(str,el))
        url=chaine.replace('\'','')
        print(url)
        #check(url)


b=trouveurdurls("http://127.0.0.1/")
```

Comment: How doesn't it work exactly? Do your url's look correct when printed...? Note that `re.findall` returns a list (and probably more than you think it should be doing), you're then adding that `list` to `liste`... Put some print statements at each stage and identify the earliest point things start looking "wrong"...

Comment: Also, adding comments to your code can make it quicker for people to understand how your code works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very surprised if the line

```
d=re.findall('<a href=".*</a>',b)
```

worked correctly. The asterisk is doing a greedy match, meaning that it finds the longest possible match. If you have more than a single link in your document, this regex will gobble up everything between the first and the end of the last link.

You should probably use the non-greedy version of the asterisk, e.g. *?.

Also, you're only interested in the href attribute, so

```
d = re.findall('<a href=".*?"', b)
```

is probably what you want. This will make the following code easier; you won't need to try and look for urls starting with http:// because you'll already have them in the `d` array. Your code as it is would also find urls that weren't part of an a's href attribute but just part of the normal text, or part of an image reference, etc.

Note that even the regex `<a href=".*?"` won't constantly produce matches, because HTML is very lazy with it's syntax, so you might also encounter strings like `<A HREF='.....'>`, `<a    href = ".....`, `<a id="something" href="......">` and so on.

You'll have to either improve the regex to match all such cases, or turn to BeautifulSoup like Evan's answer or a full-fledged HTML parser that takes care of it for you.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, about the regex, i've done the line d = re.findall('<a href=".*?"', b) because i doesn't want to store in my array d, links like id or mailto which doesn't start with http. I've tried to install pip, requests ans beautiful soup like Evan's answer, but i need to install a "parser library" but in windows shell it's writing ="  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement parser (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for parser " , i will come back to python 2.7 maybe it will work.

Comment: Make sure your regex doesn't depend on the href attribute coming before any other valid attributes - an 'a' element can have other attributes besides 'href' and they might come *before* the 'href'. Also, HTML allows more than just a single space for whitespace, and both " and ' can be used to delimit attribute values. Your regex should take all that into account if you're dealilng with HTML whose generation you don't control.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that uses "requests." It scrapes the page for urls, then checks each of the urls for their Response codes (200 means it worked, etc).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = 'http://the.web.site'

r = requests.get(page)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

urls = []

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    urls.append(a.get('href'))

url_responses = {}

for url in urls:
    temp_r = requests.get(url)
    url_responses[url] = temp_r.status_code
```

Comment: I think you want the `href` attribute of the `a` elements - not the entire contents... Also, you may as well use `requests.head` to svae bandwith as you only want to check if the server will provide a response as you're not caring about the content.

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake @Jon Clements, I changed the 'href' portion. I didn't modify it to request only the head, but you are absolutely right for pages where bandwidth would be an issue.